# How can I pass a parameter to a @ngrx/component-store selector?

Tags: angular, ngrx, component-store

Is there a way (or is it even appropriate) to pass a parameter to @ngrx/component-store selector? I was excited about component-store because *effects* and *updaters* can take an Observable as a parameter. This means that that Observable does not have to be subscribed to in a component. But there is not appeared to be a way to use an Observable as a parameter to a selector.

Answer (score 4):

```
 selectMovie(movieId: string) {
    return this.select((state) => state.movies.find(m => m.id === movieId));
 }
```

I still wonder how to pass *movieId* as an Observable and return values from selector when *movieId* or state was modified.

Comment: You can pass one or more observables to `select` as parameters, followed by a projection function which then maps values from each observable to a result. If you look at the answer with the method signature of `select` you can see this with one observable, but you can also have `S2`, `S3` etc.

Comment: This creates a new selector every time `selectMovie` is called. I'm not sure how internals work, but are selectors registered somewhere at the store? Don't we get an increasing number of "dead" selectors that aren't disposed?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by one [of the signatures](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/component-store/src/component-store.ts#L174-L178):

```js
  select<R, S1>(
    s1: Observable<S1>,
    projector: (s1: S1) => R,
    config?: SelectConfig
  ): Observable<R>;
```

I think you can achieve what you're looking for by doing:

```js
select(observable1$, () => {})
```

You can have use more than one observable, as long as the last arguments are (in this order) either the `projectioFn` and `configObject` or only the `projectionFn`.

Answer (score 1):

What I was trying to do is to pass an Observable as a parameter into a selector and get Observable back when the parameter or the State would change. I think I did get it to work. Here is the code snippet

```
readonly widgets$: Observable<Widget[]> = this.select(state => state.widgets);

widgetsByColor2$(color$: Observable<string>) { 
    return combineLatest(color$, this.widgets$).pipe(
        tap(([color, widgets]) => {
            console.log('color:', color);
            console.log('widgets:', widgets);
         ),
         map(([color, widgets]) => widgets.filter(widget => widget.color == color))
    );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can create [selectors that take parameters](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#using-selectors-with-props):

```js
export const widgetsByColor = createSelector(
   (t: Widget[], props: { color: string }) => t.widgets, (state, props) => {
       return t.widgets.filter(w => w.color == props.color)[0];
   }
);
```

Use like this:

```js
this.store
  .select(t => widgetsByColor(t, { color: 'blue' }))
    .subscribe(t => {
       ...
    }
)
```

It is not recommended to take observables as parameters (although you could) as it hinders [Memoization](https://medium.com/swlh/memoization-with-selectors-in-ngrx-c60e67a08161) as an optimization.

Comment: This question is about the @ngrx/component-store, not about the default store.